# Can I get an equivalent query for this Not in Query

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, aggregate, time, query-performance

```
SELECT ID FROM dbo.SomeTable
            WHERE ID not in
            (
                SELECT MIN(ID)
                FROM dbo.SomeTable
                GROUP BY SystemNo
            )
```

As this query is taking very long (more than a minute) to get executed. I guess "IN" is the culprit for this. I would like a query which yield same result but with most efficient time.

Comment: @MartinSmith,An Unique Clustered index is present on the ID column and there is only one index built on the table

Comment: Why are you grouping by SystemNo in the inner query?  The MIN ID will still be the MIN, will it not?

Comment: @datagod ...Nope.....otherwise it will return a single value. Different SystemNo can have same Id, so the purpose is to get the min ID for different SystemNo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't select those ids that are minimum in their systemno group so you select only those that have a lower id in their group:

```
SELECT id FROM dbo.SomeTable st1
WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.SomeTable st2
    WHERE st1.SystemNo = st2.SystemNo AND st2.id < st1.i
  )
```

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Guess that's what I get for being lazy and editing the original paste. Thanks.

Comment: The query really worked. Thanks @JakubKania !

Comment: @mehmoodshah, don't forget to mark Jakup Kania's solution as the answer.